# Treeview selected node valuepath or Datapath returns same path for nodes with same variable names

Tags: xpath, treeview

I am trying to fetch the selected node from a treeview bound to a xml , wherein the XML being used shows the below feature, Lot of nodes with same names repeated

```
<teams>
<team name="Team1" std="-1">1</team>
<team name="Team2" std="-2">0</team>
</teams>
```

within the SelectedNodeChanged function i wrote :

```
string name = xmlTreeView.SelectedNode.DataPath;
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename.xml);
XElement rows = xDoc.XPathSelectElement(name);
```

But whenever i click on the Treeview nodes it selects only the first Team element.

eg img : whenever i click both the nodes i always end up with getting First Team element in SelectedNode.DataPath

[image]

I have read lot of Stack Overflow solutions but instead of passing the arguments in Xpath, i would like to get this solved by selecting from treeview click , since i could select any of the xml nodes and dont want to hardcode a Xpath solution , i have a little idea if this can be done dynamically with Xpath , if am wrong please correct me.

Or is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the TreeView with the XML document.   When you click the TreeView, you need the clicked node to provide enough information to identify the XML node.  You can use the Tag property to add information to the TreeView node to identify the XML node.